# Find the value of n , using eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am unable to think how shall I proceed. 
I have to find value of n given a 2×2 matrix and an eigenvector.
Can somebody help me out.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -n \\ -3 & 2 n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ for some scalar $\lambda$.

Expanding this out, you have two equations: $1+n = \lambda$, $-3-2n = - \lambda$. Solving these equations together gives $-2 -n = 0$ or $n=-2$.

Comment: Thank you very much..you explained it so easily.

Comment: @AbhishekChandra As you're new here, I would suggest you to accept answers if you feel they have properly answered you. For the best experience on this website, you're advised not to hold grudges as it will not be beneficial for anyone. Hope you have a good experience (and don't forget to edit your question).